# What are some ways to add authentication for webapp using Reactjs as frontend & rails api backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, authentication, authorization

**Summary**
I'm looking to create a custom webapp for a client and need to add user authentication and authorization to it.

In previous apps where auth wasn't needed, I would split up my frontend (using React.js) and backend (Rails API) and simply have the frontend make `fetch` requests to the backend.

I've been doing some digging online and have looked into Auth0, React on Rails, and other tutorials but they've been outdated or confusing.

Does anyone have suggestions for how to add user authentication (first priority) to this kind of setup?  (I'm open to different structures as well - doesn't have to be separate backend and front end)  I'd also be happy to hear how others have done authorization in this kind of scenario as well.

Recent tutorials, videos, and personal setup's you've used in the past appreciated. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Some helpful resources I've found are:
https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api
https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-add-auth0-authentication-to-a-ruby-on-rails-api
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails

Comment: Try this gem: [rails_jwt_auth](https://github.com/rjurado01/rails_jwt_auth)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `token-based` authentication or `session-base` authentication.